# Suspend to RAM not working

Tags: power-management, laptop, suspend, polkit

I get following error when I try to suspend my laptop:

```
failed to check authorisation: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Service.Unknown:
The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
```

Which I understand as telling me that PolicyKit is not installed. The problem is, on my second laptop, which has identical OS and almost identical HW, suspend works fine without `PolicyKit`.

I know I could fix my problem by installing the `policykit-1` package, but I am wondering whether PolicyKit is necessary for suspend to work - obviously not, because it works without on my other laptop.

I have no idea how PolicyKit is supposed to work. For reasons beyond this discussion, I would very much like to avoid having to install it.

**Can I use suspend without having to install `policyKit` ?**

I am using Debian Wheezy and LXDE

The other commands: "Shutdown" and "Restart" work fine. Also, my user is in group `powerdev`:

```
powerdev:x:108:martin
```

By "suspend", I mean "suspend to RAM".

Comment: Following.  I have a similar issue although `PolicyKit` is installed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158494/the-name-org-freedesktop-policykit1-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files

Comment: What groups is your user in on the 2 systems? The cmd. `id -a` on each system as the user that owns the desktop.

Comment: @slm - `id -a` gives the same output on both systems: `uid=1000(martin) gid=1000(martin) groups=1000(martin),29(audio),108(powerdev)`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are using systemd. If that is true then use its built-in tool `systemctl`:

```
systemctl suspend
systemctl hibernate
systemctl hybrid-sleep
systemctl reboot
systemctl poweroff
systemctl halt
```

As always you can create an alias for any of these commands.

Comment: no, no, no. I am not using `systemd` (and I never will)

Answer (score 1):

What about `pm-utils`?

Typing `pm-suspend` at the console suspends on demand.

You can install both `acpid` and `acpi-support` to sleep your laptop when you close the lid.  You have to uncomment `LID_SLEEP=true` in `/etc/default/acpi-support` to get the lid working.

It did not require `policykit-1` for me, but for full disclosure I am on jessie.

Comment: I have `pm-utils` installed and `pm-suspend` from console works OK. But still I have the problem when using the "Suspend" button from the "Logout" menu in `LXDE`.

Comment: @MartinVegter - Regarding your other computer that _does_ suspend: is it possible to do `dpkg --get-selections > working_computer.txt` and `dpkg --get-selections > not_working_computer.txt`; then get the two files in the same directory, and do `diff working_computer.txt not_working_computer.txt`?  That will tell you what is installed on one machine but not the other.  Then you may be able to narrow down the troublesome packages.