# The name > org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files

Tags: centos, users, polkit

When attempting to launch `system-config-users` from command line, I get the following warning, and the tool does not open.   I'm using CentOS 7 with Mate 1.8.1.

> WARNING **: Error enumerating actions:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
>   org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
>
> Error checking for authorization org.freedesktop.policykit.exec:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
>   org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files

yum list polkit*

```
Installed Packages
polkit.x86_64   0.112-5.el7 @anaconda
polkit-devel.x86_64 0.112-5.el7 @base    
polkit-docs.noarch 0.112-5.el7 @base    
polkit-gnome.x86_64 0.105-6.el7 @epel    
polkit-pkla-compat.x86_64 0.1-4.el7  @anaconda
```

What is missing from my system to cause this error?

Comment: Do you happen to be using XFCE?

Comment: I'm using Mate 1.8.1

Comment: Since I can't tell what services are being enumerated, I can't tell you which package to install.  The error is not caused by policykit, but by one of the services policykit is attempting to load.  XFCE has this issue with `udisks`

Comment: Is there a way to monitor what services policykit is using or attempting to use?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Pre-systemd systems use policykit/consolekit in conjuction with Dbus to enforce login permissions.  This leads to two possibilities. 1. The user you're logged in as is not a member of `some group`, and `some group` has permission to access the missing service. 2. One of the services monitored by `system-config-users` is not installed.  As a hunch, search your package repo for `mate-polkit`

Comment: `Package mate-polkit-1.8.0-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. 

My user account is also missing the shutdown option in the System menu.  To turn the system off, I have to go to command and issue `sudo yum shutdown -h now`.

Comment: That maybe part of the issue.  Search for the package upower or pm-utils and post the results.

Comment: `Installed Packages   pm-utils.x86_64 1.4.1-26.el7   @anaconda`

Comment: `Installed Packages upower.x86_64 0.9.20-7.el7`

Comment: Are you in the `wheel` group?

Comment: Yes - I am in the `wheel` group.

Comment: You might want to watch [your exact question, by someone else with a bounty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158020/suspend-to-ram-not-working) as the policykit error is the same, just the input is different.  In the meantime, I've got to munch on this awhile.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

I just had the same return when installing deluged on arch, I typed:

```
 systemctl start deluged
```

I tried with sudo and it worked fine. Seems to be a group permissions issue.

All I did was enable permissions for my user account and then typed:

```
 sudo systemctl start deluged
```

worked like a charm.

Comment: Really weird message, unlike *nix. Would never have thought this would be the solution! Thanks!

Comment: Ah right, of course sudo. It would be really helpful if they had a system in place which would return an error like "root privileges required" or something a little more obvious.

Comment: Possibly the most counter-intuitive error ever.

Comment: It's probably complaining that you don't have Polkit set up which you would need to allow non-user systemctl without root privileges. Just a guess though

Comment: Worked for me too, thx

Comment: "You need to have Start Service Permissions (like root) to do this operation" would have made that error message so much easier to understand.

Comment: Just sudo on original command fixes this, no need to install deluged.

Answer (score 138):

To clarify and summarize [SNP22's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166785/105615): You probably just forgot `sudo`.:

```
sudo systemctl [...]
```

Absolutely misleading warning ...

Comment: Probably join the list of bad error message reports https://github.com/systemd/systemd/labels/needs-better-log-message but I need to test it with the latest version first...

Comment: THIS!! when you try to do a `systemctl daemon-reload` without root, it will report a weird error like this. Just check if it is missing the `sudo` or executing in the correct user or you enabled the `root` execution (in ansible the `become: true`)

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported [in this issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13865) and fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/7edd8fb198f3e8a95677df8a8f5016ed40dcff54), which was released in systemd v244.

...but unfortunately this change will never go back to Centos 7's systemd v219.